# How is setting the system-wide cryptographic policy for Java supposed to work?

Tags: security, java, rhel8, cryptography, logjam

When migrating a proprietary Java (and Jetty) based application from RHEL7 to RHEL8 I learned something new: At least with OpenJDK 11 the JVM still [defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-A41282C3-19A3-400A-A40F-86F4DA22ABA9) to a 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman group unless one specifies the system property `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize`. Nobody noticed before since all client connections are handled via a Load Balancer but this was finally discovered because a Python client running on the same host wasn't able to connect anymore due to the `DEFAULT` [system-wide cryptographic policy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening) which requires at least 2048 bits.

While setting this system property solved the issue, digging into the badly documented logic around `update-crypto-policies(8)` showed some config entries which hint that this system property should be set already according to the policy.

At least in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/conf/security/java.security` there exists a cryptic comment which refers to a file managed by that tool:

```
# Determines whether this properties file will be appended to
# using the system properties file stored at
# /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config
#
security.useSystemPropertiesFile=true
```

And that file is a symlink which indeed contains these system properties when the `DEFAULT` policy is chosen:

```
jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DH keySize < 2048, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2, DHE_DSS, RSA_EXPORT, DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, DH_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon, ECDH_anon, DH_RSA, DH_DSS, ECDH, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DES_CBC, RC4_40, RC4_128, DES40_CBC, RC2, HmacMD5
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms=
```

Oddly, for the `LEGACY` policy it tries to set a 1023 bit key size:

```
jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=1023
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1023
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DH keySize < 1023, SSLv3, SSLv2, RSA_EXPORT, DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, DH_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon, ECDH_anon, DH_RSA, DH_DSS, ECDH, DES_CBC, RC4_40, DES40_CBC, RC2, HmacMD5
jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms=3DES_EDE_CBC, RC4_128
```

Whichever policy is set, the server will always use 1024 bits which I verified via `sleep 1 | openssl s_client -tls1_2 -cipher EDH -connect rhel8.example:443 | grep "Server Temp Key"`

I didn't find any Jetty related issue which indicates that this wouldn't work there but didn't check yet if this affects these proprietary applications only. But setting that property explicitly via `-D` works so I don't see why setting those properties indirectly shouldn't work either.  (It would probably also work to add an explicit `-Djava.security.properties=/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/java.config` to the command line.)

I also couldn't find any official documentation on `security.useSystemPropertiesFile`.

So how and in which context is this supposed to work anyway? And is there maybe some documentation somewhere which I missed?